# Constraint do Hibernate de CPF não aceita CPF válidos?

Tags: hibernate, validação, constraint

Estou tentando executar a constraint de validação de CPF do Hibernate, mas ele simplesmente parece rejeitar CPF válidos. O mesmo teste usando a constraint de Email [funciona normalmente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22212926/2387977):

```
EmailValidator validator = new EmailValidator();
validator.isValid("email@test.com", null);
```

Mas a de CPF, não:

```
CPFValidator cpfValidator = new CPFValidator();
cpfValidator.isValid("755.611.810-09", null);
```

Qual é o segredo? Estou usando a versão 5.3.6.Final do Hibernate Validator. Tentei remover a pontuação, mas o resultado é o mesmo: CPF não é válido.

Comment: Tentou enviar apenas os números?

Comment: Tentei sim! Olhando o fonte do CPFValidator, ele trata (ou deveria tratar) os dois casos: com e sem pontuação.

Comment: consegue colocar a fonte do CPFValidator ou a lógica que ele usa para validar?

Comment: O código é um pouco extenso, pois ele aproveita métodos de outras classes. Mas a classe principal pode ser visualizada aqui: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/hv/br/CPFValidator.java. Tentei entender o problema com o debug na classe, mas acabei desistindo.

Comment: vi que foi colocado um tratamento para aceitar nesse formato xxxxxxxxx-xx tentou fazer um teste dessa forma?

Comment: Qual o motivo do downvote?

Comment: Não sei, mas não fui eu. Se encontrou a resposta, adiciona ela.

Comment: @EmanuelF, infelizmente não encontrei..